# Assign different (windows) users for different WCF service under same application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

Consider I am having 3 WCF services Svc1, Svc2 and Svc3. I want to authenticate all users by using Windows Authentication but I want to authorize Svc1 to User1 (Windows Authen), Svc2 to User2 (Windows Authen), Svc3 to User3 (Windows Authen).

Currently I can authorize one or many users to all the services through IIS and I have all the above services under same project (application). How can I achieve the above? Is there is any way to configure the specific user for specific service like above?

Comment: Note: Authentication and Authorization are 2 different things (related as authorization requires authentication). Showing how "Currently I can authorize" is implemented may help to clarify what you have problem with.

Comment: I want to Authenticate the users by Windows Authentication but I want to Authorize only the specific users for the service. I don't want any role based/claim based authorization here. I just want only my specific users to consume my service. i hope this clarifies..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link to [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731200(v=vs.110).aspx) explaining the authorization of WCF services using attributes.

Specified as

```
[PrincipalPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "DomainName\UserName"]
```

Comment: Thanks.. This works fine but the Name has to have "DomainName\\Username" rather than "DomainName\UserName".